# clr-wizard - how to run some code when opened

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

Using the clr-wizard I need to run some code when the wizard is opened.

The clrWizardOpenChange is not emitted when the value is changed through the clrWizardOpen Input - see [this github issue](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/1189).

Any suggestion of doing that?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of logic you plan to write when wizard is opened?

Answer (score 2):

That is intentional so you don't have a circular loop of the input and output firing. That is what the issue you linked to is trying to describe, because if you emit the output when the input is set, it triggers another round of change detection until the browser crashes.

The easiest option is to setup an event handler that you call when you open the wizard. Instead of just setting `(click)="wizardOpen = true"` you would do `(click)="openWizard()"` and inside of the `openWizard` method do the extra logic.

If you provide a working sample I can suggest more specific actions, but this is essentially just wrapping the logic to set the modal state and your other code into a function.

Comment: This is a good idea but it force to do the logic at the container component instead of the wizard.

Comment: The logic of the open state is already in the container component, and the Wizard itself is not a component you control so you can't add code inside of it. There isn't a better place to put it.